# PHP4 - "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function()"

Tags: php, php4

Second time I've ran into this...

I have function `foo()` that has a helper function inside called `formatStr()` which is used in an `array_map()` call.  When I call `foo()` more than once within a script I get a "Fatal error: Cannot redelcare `formatStr()`".  Which leads me to believe `formatStr()` is not declared locally in the function but globally.  Is this true?  Can you get around this with `function_exists()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a function defined within the foo() function? If so, move it out.

Otherwise, just wrap formatStr() within function_exists()...

```
if (!function_exists('formatStr'))
{
    function formatStr()
    {
        // Your function code
    }
}
```

Comment: I know, but it seems wrong to muck up the global name space with a helper function.  I guess I will have to wait to we upgrade to PHP5 so I can use anonymous functions.  Thanks.